# Entity Framework Include Depth

Tags: entity-framework, include, relational-database

I have a database with three tables Location, Event and Ticket with a foreign key constraint between Location and Event and Event and Ticket. When I perform a query something like context.LocationSet then the Events are not retrieved from the database. So far so good. In that case I use a query like context.LocationSet.Include("Events"). In this case every location contains the events and thats exactely what I want.

Now my question: Are the tickets also included in that second query. I mean I cannot use a query like context.LocationSet.Include("Events").Include("Tickets") since Tickets is not a property of a location object. I'm bit confused about this. So my question in general is: are relations of relations also included when i use include?! hope you know what I mean :-)

thanks for your help to make me understand!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, tickets are not automatically included when you say `context.LocationSet.Include("Events")`, but you should be able to use the following:

```
context.LocationSet.Include("Events.Tickets")
```

As with events, "`Tickets`" is the name of the **property** on your event entity, not the name of the entity class itself...

Comment: Is there any better way to avoid the hard code "Events.Tickets"? thanks.